# How to add a disabled submit button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a submit button in a form in ruby

```
f.submit btn_text, class: "btn btn-one mgt12 mgb12", id: "btn_id"
```

I want to make this button disabled by ruby without using any javascript

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `disabled: true` option.

```
f.submit btn_text,
  class: "btn btn-one mgt12 mgb12",
  id: "btn_id",
  disabled: true
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon Arup's answer, adding `disabled: true` as an argument in your `f.submit` would generate the following HTML:

```
<input class="btn btn-one mgt12 mgb12" disabled="disabled" id="btn_id" name="commit" type="submit" value="#{btn_text}">
```

Furthermore, if you want to select the disabled input for custom styling, you can do the following:

```
input[disabled="disabled"] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```